# Trying Context in SciTE on windows, but

Tags: context-mkii

I've decided to give ConTeXt a try and I've been using these instructions http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Windows_Installation:_ConTeXt_Suite_with_SciTe

If I type context --version in powershell (Windows 8.1) I get the message

```
mtx-context     | ConTeXt Process Management 0.61  
mtx-context     |
mtx-context     | main context file: C:/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/context.mkiv
mtx-context     | current version: 2014.09.06 20:59PS C:\context>
```

So I'm thinking it has installed alright, and if I type in `$env:path` I get the path variable in which I can find `C:\context\tex\texmf-win64\bin;C:\Ruby193\bin`.  So both ruby should be installed and both ruby and ConTeXt should be in the path.

But after installing SciTe (I have tried reinstalling too), and copying all the described files from the ConTeXt folder into the SciTe folder I can't seem to build my first helloworld ConTeXt file.

I'm trying

```
\starttext

Hello, world!

\stoptext
```

But when I press build I get

```
>texexec --pdf helloworld.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
pdftex: The memory dump file could not be found.
pdftex: Data: cont-en.fmt
>Exit code: 1
```

I'm thinking maybe the problem is related to it talking about MikTex, where it should maybe be calling some ConTeXt thing instead?

Also in the tutorial it was written I should press ctrl+F12 to build, but I could never get this to work and found F7 instead.

Many thanks beforehand

Comment: You have found the problem. Texexec is running miktex pdftex instead of context pdftex. Edit you path so that the context bin- directory is before the miktex bin-directory. If you want to run miktex and context in parallell, you probably have to start context from a batch file setting the correct path.